# Method to display the page execution time

Tags: performance

Is there a method to display the page execution time? I have a usecase that needs to display page execution time on a lightning component on a partner community portal.

Comment: Have you looked at [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)? Calling `performance.measure(null)` would give you time since the page started to load, for example.

Comment: thanks a lot, @sfdcfox, I tried some methods in javascript but is not accurate.